# xcode template change framework path

Tags: xcode, project, xcode-template

Is it possible in the templateInfo.plist to change where a framework is loaded from?

I can't seem to find how to change it with the framework also being installed to the iPhoneOS#.#SDK and iPhoneSimulatorOS#.#SDK System/Library/Frameworks directories.

I have my framework loading from those directories where it is installed but I have a request to change the template to load the framework from another install location to minimize disk space.

Example plist xml:

```
<key>Frameworks</key>
        <array>
            <string>MobileCoreServices</string>
            <string>My_New_SDK</string>
            <string>AddressBook</string>
            <string>AddressBookUI</string>
            <string>AudioToolbox</string>
            <string>AVFoundation</string>
            <string>CFNetwork</string>
            <string>CoreGraphics</string>
            <string>CoreLocation</string>
            <string>CoreTelephony</string>
            <string>ExternalAccessory</string>
            <string>Foundation</string>
            <string>MapKit</string>
            <string>MessageUI</string>
            <string>MediaPlayer</string>
            <string>Security</string>
            <string>SystemConfiguration</string>
            <string>QuartzCore</string>
            <string>UIKit</string>
        </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the My_New_SDK from the frameworks list of the target area of the template, you can create a Node in the template for the framework and specify the absolute path in that node. Do not forget to add the node to the Nodes array in the template plist

```
<key>MY_New_SDK.framework</key>
<dict>
<key>Path</key>
<string>/PATH_TO_FRAMEWORK/My_New_SDK.framework</string>
    <key>PathType</key>
    <string>Absolute</string>
</dict>
```